# Show the height of a cone inside a cone, is given by $h = 15 -3r$

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry

A small cone is enclosed within a larger cone as shown in the diagram below. The large cone has height $15$cm and radius $5$cm. Let $h$ represent the height of the small cone and $r$ represent the radius.

Show $h = 15 - 3r$

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? And most people aren't going to look at a link in case it has malware. So edit your post to include your working and the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple ratio problem involving similar triangles. But you must focus on the small upper cone rather than the inverted cone.

The small cone at the top of the large cone has height $15-h$ and has the same base as the small inverted cone, so its radius is also $r$.

Because of similar triangles the ratio of height to base of the small upper cone is the same as the ratio of height to base of the larger cone.

\begin{equation}
\dfrac{15-h}{r}=\dfrac{15}{5}=3
\end{equation}

Giving

\begin{eqnarray}
15-h&=&3r\\
h&=&15-3r
\end{eqnarray}